# Error: internal at new HttpsErrorImpl when invoking Firebase https callable cloud functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

This is the error I get whenever I call manageSubscription() which invokes the https callable cloud function:

```
core.js:4081 ERROR Error: internal
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (index.cjs.js:60)
    at _errorForResponse (index.cjs.js:155)
    at Service.<anonymous> (index.cjs.js:560)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27149)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
```

Using:

```
"@angular/core": "^10.0.4",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",
```

Here is my Apps Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    SharedComponentsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ORIGIN, useValue: 'http://localhost:5001' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I am invoking https callable cloud function in my Service:

Added dependency:

```
constructor(private firebaseFunctions: AngularFireFunctions) {}
```

This is the method:

```
public manageSubscription(){
  this.firebaseFunctions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');

  const functionRef = this.firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable('testFunction');
  functionRef({ returnUrl: 'window.location.origin' })
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
  });
}
```

This is the cloud function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.testFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log('reached');
  return { date: true };
});
```

I can't see the calls made to this function in the cloud function logs or in the chrome dev console Network tab. What am I doing wrong?

I tried both cloud functions emulator and live app. Still no luck!

I have been trying to debug this since the past 3 days and have lost a bit of hair and weight :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not the only one who lost hair because of this issue.
I solved by simply updating the **firebase** package in the client (I did the same thing on Friday but it wasn't solved yet)
**The version 7.22.0 was coded by the devil, upgrade it to 7.22.1** and you'll hopefully be fine.

Comment: 1) You deserve all my internet points. 
2) There is no documentation to be found regarding this issue - do you have a reference for us?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3890 found some details here